# How to get the end of string with preg_match?

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I got this string:

```
from:100000238267321=to:100000238267322=somethingelse: hey james, heard the news, mike is returning tomorrow!
```

And this preg_match command:

```
#(?P<from>(?:\w|\s)+):(?P<idfrom>\d+)=(?P<to>(?:\w|\s)+):(?P<toid>\d+)=(?P<somethingelse>(?:\w|\s)+):(?P<somethingelsetxt>(?:\w|\s)+)#
```

And i needed to get all the text after the 'somethingelse:' part. With the preg_match above it only gets until the comma after 'hey james'. Returning:

```
[0] from:100000238267321=to:100000238267322=somethingelse:hey james
[from]  from
[1] from
[idfrom]    100000238267321
[2] 100000238267321
[to]    to
[3] to
[toid]  100000238267322
[4] 100000238267322
[somethingelse] somethingelse
[5] somethingelse
[somethingelsetxt]  hey james
[6] hey james
```

What could i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.*$` to get everything from the current point to the end of the string. Make sure the `multiline` modifier is set so that `.` matches newlines, unless you know for certain that there won't be any newlines.

Comment: It means "the end of the string".

Comment: Would a ? be better, or would it act the same?  The ? makes the * ungreedy.

Comment: In this context the `?` would make no difference, because "all characters until the end of the string" and "as few characters as possible until the end of the string" are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the last array value:

```
$string = 'from:100000238267321=to:100000238267322=somethingelse: hey james, heard the news, mike is returning tomorrow!';
$value = explode(':',$string);
echo $value[3];
```

See [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/heZQIw).

### UPDATE

To fix your regex problem, add "|," to your somethingelsetxt regex, like so:

```
(?P<somethingelsetxt>(?:\w|\s|,)
```

That will get the comma too.  You could include a "|!" as well if you want.

Comment: Update worked as well, but i'm gonna keep with the explode so if the user puts in different characters like '*' or '&' and all of that.

Comment: If the text after `somethingelse:` will always be at the end, then you can replace the final piece of the regex with `.*`.